# Incompatible flow-type for generic higher order function

Tags: flowtype

Flow says that the type that is being returned by `voidnullify` below is incompatible. I think I am missing something?

```
import faker from 'faker'

type P =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean

function voidnullify(func: () => P): ?P {
  const random: number = faker.random.number({
    min: 1, 
    max: 10
  })

  const result = func()

  if (random <= 7) return result
  else if (random <= 9) return null
  else return undefined
}

function someBoolean() {
  return true
}

function someString() {
  return "hello"
}

function someNumber() {
  return 1
}

let maybeNum: ?number
let maybeStr: ?string
let maybeBool: ?boolean

maybeNum = voidnullify(someNumber) 
maybeStr = voidnullify(someString) 
maybeBool = voidnullify(someBoolean)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're doing the way you're trying to do it is just unsupported. I'm not sure if it *should* work, but as you're trying to just guard the input types (it looks like?), the proper way to do that in Flow is with bounded polymorphism + generic parameters:

```
type P =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean

function voidnullify<A: P>(func: () => A): ?A {
  const random: number = faker.random.number({
    min: 1, 
    max: 10
  })
  ...
```

Comment: If I change P to X, or if I remove one of the union types, Flow still tells "no errors", which is a false positive.